# Converting a URI path to an absolute file system path in .NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

In C# ASP.Net, How do I convert:

From: http://example.com/foo/bar.html
To: C:\WebServerRoot\foo\bar.html

Answer (score 3):

Considering that "example.com" is a web server running  ASP.NET app the following code returns a local (physical) path to a file:

```
var server =  HttpContext.Current.Server;
string filePath = server.MapPath("/foo/bar.html");
```

Comment: ah, now _that_ looks believable.  The URL data is in the _input_ to taht function, @Rodolfo